# Cómo puedo arrancar programa en pendrive nada mas meterlo?

Tags: python

quisiera saber si puedo hacer que en cuanto se meta el pendrive se puede ejecutar un programa al instante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supongo que si quieres que arranque un programa que has hecho tu en Python deberías tener una ruta de configuración que pille las variables de entorno desde el pendrive, por otra parte, lo de arrancar nada mas meter el pendrive, deberías hacer un autorun .inf dentro del pendrive y decirle cual es el programa que quieres que inicie